# .NetCore 2.0 - MVC View Error - IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a basic CRUD application. On my Details view, I am having an error as per screenshot.

[image]

I created a ViewModel to display my Index view. (multiple members). I am trying to reuse that ViewModel to display the Details view (single member).

Can someone spot what I am doing wrong:

Here is my Details view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<GymTracker.ViewModel.MemberViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <div>
        <h4>Member</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">



            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaymentType)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentType)
            </dd>

        </dl>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.MemberID">Edit</a> |
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
}
```

Here is my Details action method in the controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        List<MemberViewModel> memberViewModel = new List<MemberViewModel>(); //declared my VIewModel instance

        var listData = await (from member in _context.Members
                              where (member.Id == id)
                              join membershiptypes in _context.MembershipTypes on member.MembershipTypeId equals membershiptypes.MembershipTypeId
                              select new
                              {
                                  member.Id,
                                  member.FirstName,
                                  member.LastName,
                                  member.DateOfBirth,
                                  membershiptypes.PaymentType
                              }
                              ).ToListAsync();

        listData.ForEach(x =>
        {
            MemberViewModel Obj = new MemberViewModel();
            Obj.MemberID = x.Id;
            Obj.FirstName = x.FirstName;
            Obj.LastName = x.LastName;
            Obj.DateOfBirth = x.DateOfBirth;
            Obj.PaymentType = x.PaymentType;
            memberViewModel.Add(Obj);


        }


        );

        //link the viewModel instance to the context class somehow..


        return View(memberViewModel);
    }
```

And finally here is the ViewModel that I am using for the Details and the Index view:

```
  namespace GymTracker.ViewModel
{
    public class MemberViewModel
    {
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public string PaymentType { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Try this:
`<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.MemberID">Edit</a> |`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, you expecting List of MemberViewModel which is your `@Model`, You are trying to access `MemberID` on List of MemberViewModel which is causing an issue.

You can need to do something like that

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.MemberID">Edit</a>
```

Or if you want to set the first MemberID for all table items. Try this:

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.FirstOrDefault().MemberID">Edit</a>
```

Comment: @Metzer, if you feel that this answer solved your problem. Please accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.MemberID">Edit</a> |
```

Your `Model` is IEnumerable of `MemberViewModel` so it doesn't have MemberID property. You're rendering that link in for each loop so you need to use `item` variable instead

Answer (score 0):

`Model` here is the sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`); an `IEnumerable<T>` *really doesn't have that property* (`@Model.MemberID`) - however, each item *in* the sequence *might*.

You might have meant:

```
@item.MemberID
```

Alternatively, if you really did mean to go back the entire sequence of items, you will need to use something like:

```
@foreach(var x in Model) {
    // do something with x
}
```

or maybe just

```
@(Model.First().MemberID)
```

or similar

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq that's ok, I don't think the odd negative vote is going to affect me all that much :)